# Make responsive image in carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my image in carousel to become responsive especially the height of the image. The width is okay but the height it makes the image only half. Can someone help me? Give me some ideas please. I just want only `500px` of height and I achieved that but i want my image height to become 100%.

Here is the picture[image]

Here is the full image 
[image]

Here is the html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/asd.png"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="top-bar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7">
                        <div class="top-bar-socials">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Governor-Andres-Pascual-CollegeNavotas-City/344134628983014?fref=ts">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/official_gapc">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/governor-andres-pascual-college-in-navotas-city">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-5 text-right">
                        <ul class="list-inline top-dark-right">                      
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> gapc_school@yahoo.com.ph</li>
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (02) 282-9036</li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="40">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            </button>
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="GAPC" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About us</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mission and Vision</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Faculty Portal</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
         <!-- Indicators -->
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
         </ol>

     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/tae.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/tubol.jpg" alt="Chania ">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/tulok.jpg" alt="Flower">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/ebak.jpg" alt="Flower">
        </div>
   </div>

     <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
   </div>
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my css code.

```
.navbar-header{
  height: 74px;
}

.navbar-toggle{
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 font-weight: 560;
 color: #949494;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 35px 2px 45px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
 line-height: 70px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav.navbar-nav > li.active a{
    color:#a92419;
    border-bottom-color: #a92419;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #a92419;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 .navbar-default{
 background-color:#fff;
 margin: 0;

 }
 .nav>li>a {
 position: relative;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
padding: 0 20px;
margin-right:6px;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav > li{
 display: :inline-block;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav{
 list-style-type:none;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color:#a92419;
   border-bottom-color: #a92419;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color:#a92419;
  margin:0 0 4px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
  background: none;
  }
  button.navbar-toggle{
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#000; 
  margin: 0px;
}
.navbar.affix {
  width: 100%;
     qposition: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color:#a92419;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 3em;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown:hover a.dropdown-toggle {
  border-bottom-color: #a92419;
  color:#a92419;
}
.top-bar-dark {
  background-color: #a92419;
}

.top-bar-light {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #32c5d2;
}
.top-bar-socials {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.top-bar-socials:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
.top-bar-socials a {
  margin: 0px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-dark-right {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.top-dark-right li {
  line-height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid #932015;
  padding: 0px 10px;

}
.top-dark-right li, .top-dark-right li a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.top-dark-right li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
a.login{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook:hover{
  color:#3b5998;
}
.fa-twitter:hover{
  color:#1dcaff;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover{
  color:#007bb5;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background: none !important;
  filter: progid: none !important;
  outline: 0;
}
.carousel-inner{
height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner img{
   height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 240px){
  .img-responsive{
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
   padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 241px) and (max-width: 320px){
   .img-responsive{
    width: 240px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
   padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px){
   .img-responsive{
    width: 250px;
    height: 65px;
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle{
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px){
   .img-responsive{
    width: 280px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle{
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
   .img-responsive{
    width: 260px;
    height:70px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
 }

}
```

Comment: can you send a link for testing ?

Comment: i dont have js fiddle sir..

Comment: try the new code in your style.css

Comment: I would use the images as backgrounds to the divs (instead of standalone img tags) and then set `background-size: contain;` to each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by adding a `max-height` to `.carousel-inner img`. Thanks for ur effort guys. hehe.

```
.carousel-inner img{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner{
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 100vh, CSS3 gives us viewport-relative units. 100vw means 100% of the viewport width. 100vh; 100% of the height. Very handy when doing full screen slides.

try this :

```
.carousel-inner img{
   height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Note : for internet explorer it's supported only by ie11, for other browsers there is no problem.

## UPDATE :

add this class to your style :

```
.item{
    height: 500px;
}

.item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/qd4xhzvm/

Comment: sir add one image and try to slide it. it only triggers when the img is active. i don't like the blinking. can you rid that sir?

Comment: yeah , i correct that and delete .active. hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: you can change the height 500px to 100vh or doing it best  by height : calc( 100vh - 60px );

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.item.active img {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```